# Word inerop c#: Finding and replacing asterisk in word file

Tags: c#, find-replace, word-interop

I am editing word files using word interop. Sometimes these files have multiples "*" which I have to replace programmatically. So, if there are two asterisks I will replace them with no. 2. 
Somehow I am not able to find the "*".

```
 Word.Range rngAff = doc.Content;    
 rngAff.Find.ClearFormatting();
 rngAff.Find.Font.Superscript = 1;
 rngAff.Find.Text = @"\*{1,}";
 while (rngAff.Find.Execute())
            {
              rngAff.Find.Replacement.Text = this.CountReplaceAsterisks()
            }
```

Somehow execute command is not successful. How to I find asterisks in word file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i need to replace some character in a word file, i am using that piece of code, and i have a good result:

```
class Program
{

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    SearchReplace();
  }


  private static void SearchReplace()
  {
    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    Application application = new Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = application.Documents.Add("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\word.docx");

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find findObject = application.Selection.Find;
    findObject.ClearFormatting();
    findObject.Text = "**";
    findObject.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
    findObject.Replacement.Text = "";

    object replaceAll = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
    findObject.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

    object filename = "C:\\savefile.docx";
    document.SaveAs2(ref filename);;

    document.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    document = null;
    application.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    application = null;
  }

}
```